# How to create a list of tuples recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

Essentially what I'm trying to do is write the enumerate function recursively. I'm fully aware that doing this recursively is not optimal and that there is already a built-in enumerate function in python.

```
def enumeration(mylist, idx=0):
    if idx == 0:
        return [(idx, mylist[idx]), enumeration(mylist, idx+1)] 
    elif idx != len(mylist)-1:
        return (idx, mylist[idx]), enumeration(mylist, idx+1)
    else:
        return idx, mylist[idx]
```

Now it's not the enumeration part that's difficult. It's getting the tuples to match up where they should be. If mylist was set to ["The", "tree", "then"], the output would be "[(0, "the"), ((1, "tree"), (2, "then"))] when I want it to look like [(0, "the"), (1, "tree"), (2, "then")].

I know what is causing the problem but I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried using '+' instead of ',' in the return statements but that just leads to [(0, "the", 1, "tree", 2, "then")] which I also don't want.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the return type of your `enumeration` is not consistent:

- if the index is 0 it returns a list[pair, enumeration()]
- if the index is neither 0 nor end-of-list, it returns a Pair[Pair, enumeration]
- if the index is end-of-list, it returns a simple pair

You need your various cases to be consistently typed in such a way that you can "recombine" your items. Since enumeration() should return a sequence, logically each recursive case needs to return a *list* (of pairs).

Then you need to do a recursive case analysis. Generally, recursion consists of *two* items:

1. how do you decide to end the recursion and what do you do in that case
2. what do you do in the normal case

Here the terminal case is pretty simple: if you're past the end of the list, just return an empty list. Incidentally this is something you're not handling at all: try calling `enumerate([])` and see what happens.

Then the normal recursive case: just generate a pair of (index, item), call enumerate() with an incremented index, and concatenate the two.

```py
def enumerate(mylist, idx=0):
    # note: terminal case is really `idx == len(mylist)`, you may want to generate an error if `idx > len(mylist)` instead as that's an incorrect use of the API
    if idx >= len(mylist):
        return []
    else:
        return [(idx, mylist[idx])] + enumerate(mylist, idx+1)
```

Other than the behaviour with empty lists, your version also uses `idx` completely differently: in the original enumerate it's just the index that's *returned*, it's not used to manipulate the input (indeed the input is not necessarily indexable). So e.g. `enumerate(range(3), 5)` would yield `(5, 0), (6, 1), (7, 2)`. Your version would either error out or end, because it would try to access the 5th item of a `range(3)`.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
def enumeration(mylist, idx=0):
    if idx == 0:
        return [(idx, mylist[idx])]+(enumeration(mylist, idx+1))
    elif idx < len(mylist)-1:
        return [(idx, mylist[idx])]+(enumeration(mylist, idx+1))
    else:
        return [(idx, mylist[idx])]
```

output:

```
mylist=["asd","gsd","fff","adf"]
enumeration(mylist, idx=0)

[(0, 'asd'), (1, 'gsd'), (2, 'fff'), (3, 'adf')]
```

First of use a list to hold the values.

Second instead of calling the next recursion with a `,` use `+` to add to the list of values , this way each tuple gets added to the same list.